# BlueZ error setting privacy on Raspbian

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to use BlueZ 5.45 on a raspberry pi running Raspbian Jessie and cannot set up BlueZ to use LE Privacy. When I start the bluetooth daemon I get the following messages:

```
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[18971]: Bluetooth daemon 5.45
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[18971]: Starting SDP server
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[18971]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[18971]: No IRK stored
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[18971]: Failed to open crypto
Jul 26 22:00:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

BlueZ tries to set up LE Privacy, finds there is no IRK stored, but does not have access to the crypto functions in the kernel to generate one.

How can I get past this error?

Privacy was set by adding the line `Privacy = device` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and adding a symlink at `/usr/local/etc`.

Answer (score 9):

In the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

Set `Privacy = off` and `ControllerMode = le`

This seems to have fixed most for me still tinkering with bluetooth to get autoconnect to mobile phone when near at boot time or thereof.

Plus edit the bluetooth.service file  `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service` as follows:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat --noplugin=sap -E
```

... and most of the errors will disappear except service change handle error.

Comment: This did fix my problem too. With Bluez 5.50 the setting is `ControllerMode = le`